# Error while update-query : AttributeError("'unicode' object has no attribute 'subtype'",)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have order structure:

```
{u'order_id': 12341,
u'status_history': [{u'reason': u'',
                      u'status': u'2000',
                      u'time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 31, 11, 52, 47)},
                    {u'reason': u'',
                     u'status': u'6020',
                     u'time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 31, 11, 59, 8)},
                    ]
}
```

I want update record. My query:

```
problem_index = 1 # int
db.order.update({'order_id':order_id},
                 {'$set':{'status_history.%s' % problem_index : edited_item}}
)
```

result:

```
AttributeError("'unicode' object has no attribute 'subtype'",)
```

why?

Comment: I've tried your query and it worked ok. What's your `edited_item`?

Comment: For example:
`{u'status': u'4200', u'problemModCompensation': 0, u'modified_field': {}, u'problemMod': 0, 'previous versions': [{...}],'editor': {'username': u'Admin', '_id': ObjectId('51cc42b10904e7fa4182e06c')}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh..recursive structure. Need more attention.
I am save last version:

```
last_item  = edited_item
# Need last_item  = copy.copy(edited_item)
if edited_item.has_key('previous versions'):
    edited_item['previous versions'].append(last_item)
```